# Make a sibling div to take the leftover height?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs :

```
 <div class="a">

    <div class="b">
    </div>
    <div class="c">
    </div>

  </div>
```

Current css :

```
.a
{
  height:300px;
  border:solid 2px red;
}

.b
{
  height:100px;
  border:solid 3px blue;
}
.c
{
  height:100%;
  border:dashed 3px gray;
}
```

[image]

The **red's height** is determined via JS ( when document ready). *( it's a popup window div which its height should has proportios to the user screen size.)*

The `blue`  has a fixed height. (title)

- Problem/question :

Is there any **css** way to make the **gray** div height to take the rest of the available height ( from the red one)

so it would look like:

[image]

[**here is the test fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/AhUhEXuK/1/edit)

NB :

browser support : IE 8+

Comment: What browser support do you need? also is the top div's height fixed?

Comment: @Itay edited. The top blue div height is a fixed height. (mentioned it)

Comment: Why are you looking for a css solution and not a jquery/javascript solution? Any specific reasons?

Comment: @TeunPronk I believe that css should be a first approach. ( unless impossible and then i'd go to js).

Comment: Dont give C (gray div) a height.. that should do the trick I suppose. Doing that should make it do an autosize. the blue div will block it and it will grow down till the bottom of red, also need position absolute.. didnt notice answer below lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/AhUhEXuK/3/edit)

```
.a
{
  position: relative;
}

.b
{
  height:100px;
}
.c
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Working. I knew about that trick to do bottom:0 top 0 . somehow it didnt work for me. now i cleaned a bit all the inline css and it's working. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am always wondering why users accept an answer within the first hour ...!?

Absolute positioning surely is one option, but often has the drawback that elements are no longer in the normal flow.

In your case there is another option: display: table(-xyz);

You only have to set the width and height of the outer container/ wrapper element - see:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzBE9/)

```
...
```

Comment: +1 You got a point. but you should talk to SO about it (allowing the answer selection after an hour ). **indeed nice solution**.

Comment: In this case, the `.a` element is positioned relative, so it is still in-flow. However, in this case, the fixed heights could cause overflow issues regardless. Using CSS table display types is most useful when you need to allow the elements to expand with the content since table cells don't have fixed heights, they always expand as needed.

Comment: @Royi: Well, the answer to your question is:"It depends ...!" ;-) One obvious advantage is that you do not have to set an explicit height for the first DIV. Personally I work a lot on Responsive Layouts/ Designs, where it is very useful to firstly use relative units like 'EMs' and secondly must not set any heights.

Comment: `1 EM` is like the size of the font of the body...right ? so i can play with the document without knowing what is the value actually...right ?

Comment: @Marc: That's not fully true.  ;-) There are two different table algorithms, which you can switch between by using '[table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout): auto|fixed'. So you can also have a table-cell to overflow.

Comment: @Royi Namir: '1em' represents the user's default font-size set in his Browser - also have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length Most modern Browsers also support 'REM', which has several advantages over 'EM'. Note that the root element for 'REM' is the HTML element (and not body). It also defaults to the user's standard font-size.

Comment: @Royi Namir The "modern" way to achieve such goals is [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). But due to your needed browser support, you would need a fallback, at least for IE 8+9. Additionally there are three different syntaxes of flexbox out there in the wild ...! And for your actual use case it also might be some kind of "overkill" ...! ;-) But I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @Royi: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/7/edit The 'line-height' is somehow very difficult to understand and I only know the German words for the "technical details". So together with checkboxes and/ or radio buttons it might be necessary to add some extra padding to the boxes/ buttons to optically align them with the text.

Comment: @Netsurfer But I dont understand why did you remove the vertical align from checkbox ...

Comment: Because the default value 'vertical-align: baseline;' in this case is the one "that fits best". So no need to set it explicitly (but you might do so e.g. if otherwise another value could be inherited).